# How to achieve deleting or updating model that doesn't effect previously created object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have three models Product, Order, and OrderItem

Once someone places an order I don't want the product object associated with the orderitem model on the receipt to change or get deleted if I were to delete or update the product model. How to achieve this?

```
#model
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField()

class Order(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Buyer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


#view
@login_required
def receipt(request):
    orderitems = OrderItem.objects.filter(order__buyer__user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

don't make it a `ForeignKey` in OrderItem for price use an integer field and provide the value for it in your view.